# Dedekind's way of construction of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

In his book *[Essays on the Theory of Numbers](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/21016/21016-pdf.pdf)*, Dedekind says

> In discussing the notion of the approach of a variable magnitude to a fixed limiting value, and especially in proving the theorem that **every magnitude which grows continually, but not beyond all limits, must certainly approach a limiting value**, I had recourse to geometric evidences.    ..........
>
> ......and a more careful investigation convinced me that this theorem, or any one equivalent to it, can be regarded in some way as a sufficient basis for infinitesimal analysis.

**Question 1.** Can one explain the meaning of bold faced statement in modern language?

**Question 2.** In the book mentioned, Dedekind shows a construction of real numbers. In first few pages of the book, he tries to explain why he want to do this? But I didn't understand his justification of *construction* of real numbers for the foundation of real analysis. Can one briefly explain his idea of foundation of real numbers?

Comment: For Question 1, that sounds like the well known theorem "an increasing bounded sequence of real numbers must converge" I believe it's called the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @Gregory: I feel your statement correct.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by Question 2?  Certainly in this brief excerpt you aren't going to find Dedekind's entire theory of the real numbers.

Comment: For question 1: If $a_0<a_1<a_2<a_3<\dotsb<C$, then the sequence $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ approaches a limit. As an example:$$1<1.1<1.11<1.111<\dotsb<2$$and the sequence $(1,1.1,1.11,1.111,\dots)$ approaches the limiting value $1.\bar1=1\frac19$.

Comment: @Eric: I edited question 2; does it make sense now?

Comment: The monotone convergence theorem isn't true for, say, the rationals. (Take the sequence $(3,3.1,3.14,\dots)$; it's increasing and bounded, but it has no limit in the rational numbers.) It _is_ true for the reals (for example, that sequence has the limit $\pi$ in the reals). To prove the monotone convergence theorem, then, he first had to explicitly define what he means by "the reals"; that is, he had to construct the reals. Only after doing that can he prove anything about them.

Comment: Much of real analysis depends on the monotone convergence theorem, so if he proves that, he essentially creates a foundation for real analysis.

Comment: Before Dedekin, we knew there were irrational numbers but we had no way to describe them other than something vague such as "all the values that can not be expressed rationally".  The rationals notoriously has many "holes" which we can indefinately approach but never reach.  More formally there are monotonically increasing bound sequences that have no rational limits.  It's clear these sequences approach ... something.  To declare (and prove) the real numbers as precisely the limits of these sequences is the fundation of analysis.